# node js getting the HTTP Request name

Tags: node.js

```
   http.createServer(function (request, response) {
   request.on("end", function () {

    if(request.method='PUT')
    {
    buf1='This is PUT';
    console.log('received PUT');
    }

       response.writeHead(200, {
         'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
      });  
      response.end('Hello HTTP!'+buf1);
   });
```

I see that even I just try to do a GET also, the PUT command is gettingexecuted. is there anything basic I am missing? all I need is my program should read all headers based on method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be `if (request.method === 'PUT') {`

I.e. you need two or three equals signs, not just one.

Comment: == is equality operator. === is identity operator. === checks type also. for eg: 1=='1' returns true, but 1==='1' returns false. since we are comparing numeric type(1) with string type('1').